# Zynq 7000: Minimum asm code to init cpu1 from cpu0

Tags: assembly, armv7, zynq, cortex-a

I'm trying to figure out the minimum requirements to initialize cpu1 from cpu0 in an amp configuration on a zynq-7000.

I have a given FSBL that hands over to u-boot with which I copy both programs (cpu0/1) from flash to different locations in ram (with `sf read ...`).

I can run both programs on cpu0 out of u-boot with `go [adr]` where adr is the start address of either program. I get the expected output on the uarts.

What does not work is that cpu0 should start cpu1 by writing its start address to register `0xffff_fff0` and after that issuing a system event `sev`.

I do not enable any caches, MMUs or the SCU because I want to keep it as simple as possible (no synchronizations or flushes) until I achieved to start up cpu1. Or is this actually the problem and I do need any of these?

Currently I only initialize the vector table, print to the uart and additionally for core 0 try to start core 1:

```
/* CPU 0 */
.section .vector_table, "x"
.global _init
_init:
    b reset     /* reset handler */
    b .         /* software interrupt */
    b .         /* prefetch abort */
    b .         /* data abort */
    b .         /* reserved */
    b .         /* irq */
    b .         /* fiq */

/* ASCII control chars */
.equ asciiLF, 0x0a
.equ asciiCR, 0x0d

.section .text
    uart1fifo: .word 0xe0001030     /* UART 1 rx/tx fifo register */

reset:
    /* Output "0" on UART 1 */
    ldr r0, uart1fifo
    mov r1, #'0'
    str r1, [r0]
    mov r1, #asciiCR
    str r1, [r0]
    mov r1, #asciiLF
    str r1, [r0]

    /* Set cpu1 start address */
    ldr r0, =0x20000000     /* CPU 1 start address */
    ldr r1, =0xfffffff0     /* Register to point to the CPU 1 start address */
    str r0, [r1]

    /* I added a 0.5s wait here which did not help */

    sev     /* Execute SEV to cause CPU 1 to wake up */

    /* Output "." on UART 1 to indicate that we actually went so far */
    ldr r0, uart1fifo
    mov r1, #'.'
    str r1, [r0]
    mov r1, #asciiCR
    str r1, [r0]
    mov r1, #asciiLF
    str r1, [r0]

    b .     /* Endless loop */
```

I can see the '0' and the '.' on uart 1 when I run the above code on cpu 0.

```
/* CPU 1 */
.section .vector_table, "x"
.global _init
_init:
    b reset     /* reset handler */
    b .         /* software interrupt */
    b .         /* prefetch abort */
    b .         /* data abort */
    b .         /* reserved */
    b .         /* irq */
    b .         /* fiq */

/* ASCII control chars */
.equ asciiLF, 0x0a
.equ asciiCR, 0x0d

.section .text
    uart0fifo: .word 0xe0000030     /* UART 0 rx/tx fifo register */

reset:
    /* Output "1" on UART 0 */
    ldr r0, uart0fifo
    mov r1, #'1'
    str r1, [r0]
    mov r1, #asciiCR
    str r1, [r0]
    mov r1, #asciiLF
    str r1, [r0]

    b .     /* Endless loop */
```

Here I can see the '1' on uart 0 when I run it on cpu 0.

I'm new to this and I'm a bit lost. Am I missing something fundamental? What can I try to get this to work?

I've been looking at xapp-1079 but this uses Xilinx' Standalone Libs and it's very difficult for me to filter out what is actually needed. I need a minimum working example so that I can port it to the exotic OS that we run on the first core.

Comment: Can you specify the u-boot commands you use to load the binaries.

Comment: @R.k.Lohana Thank you for the comment. It turned out that CPU1 wasn't in WFE state. I suppose it was already woken up by u-boot although I can't see the reason why it should do this as the CPU1 state was not SMP. I'll put the steps that actually succeeded in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that cpu1 wasn't in wfe state. I suppose u-boot has already woken it up although it wasn't using it i.e. the state of cpu1 was not smp.

I had to execute a software reset on cpu 1 and bring it back into wfe state before issuing the `sev` command according to [AR#53828 from xilinx](https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/53828.html).

The steps should the link die were:

- Backup the registers that are overwritten in the next steps.
- Restore the WFE (wait for event) code in the OCM area. (I used assembly instead of the shown xilinx xsct commands as I don't have access to their IDE):

```
mwr 0xFFFFFF00 0xe3e0000f
mwr 0xFFFFFF04 0xe3a01000
mwr 0xFFFFFF08 0xe5801000
mwr 0xFFFFFF0C 0xe320f002
mwr 0xFFFFFF10 0xe5902000
mwr 0xFFFFFF14 0xe1520001
mwr 0xFFFFFF18 0x0afffffb
mwr 0xFFFFFF1C 0xe1a0f002
```

- Write the jump instruction to `0x0` that takes cpu1 from `0x0` to the wfe area  at `0xffffff00`:

```
mwr 0x00000000 0xe3e0f0ff
```

- Perform a software reset on cpu1:

```
mwr 0xf8000008 0xdf0d    # slcr unlock
mwr 0xf8000244 0x2       # A9_RST1_ASSERT
mwr 0xf8000244 0x22      # A9_RST1_ASSERT | A9_CLKSTOP1
mwr 0xf8000244 0x20      # A9_CLKSTOP1
mwr 0xf8000244 0x0       # de-assert / start all
mwr 0xf8000004 0x767b    # slcr lock
```

- Write the cpu1 start address to `0xfffffff0`.
- Issue `sev`.
- Ensure that cpu1 actually started or just wait a few cycles.
- Restore the backed up registers.